# Error 403 when trying to scrape a pages title using apify web-scraper actor

Tags: apify

I am trying to use apify to get a websites title but when I run the code I get error 403, anyone know a fix?

My Code:

```
currentLink = "https://medium.com/vice/scientists-monitored-631-people-as-they-died-this-is-what-they-found-2de48ad9ed96";

const postUrl = "https://api.apify.com/v2/actor-tasks/LdLPzP6nopWgexrqX/run-sync-get-dataset-items?token=" + token;

var values = {
    contentType: "application/json",
    "startUrls": [{
        "url": currentLink,
    }]
};

$.ajax({
    url: postUrl,
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(values),
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response.data); // Actor run object
        getItemsFromDataset(response.data.defaultDatasetId);
    }

});
```

I get this as my error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
attached with a link that shows me the correct results.

Comment: which server responded to a 403? the medium or the apify run endpoint?

Comment: @pocesar the apify run endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `run-sync-get-dataset-items` endpoint, which returns dataset (and only dataset, i.e. the items array, not the run object). Then you're trying to get the items, assuming you're providing `defaultDatasetId`, which is `undefined` in this case. In the end, you get an error. This would also explain why you see the items via the link.

Not sure why it's error 403, not 404, but I don't see the implementation of getItemsFromDataset(). Could you please check the above first?